# VHDL Counter returning 'X', unknown value

Tags: binary, vhdl, counter, vlsi, digital-design

I am trying to create a 4 bit counter with instantiated components, shown below. When I simulate, the output toggles between 0 and X(an unknown signal). I'm not sure what is wrong.
simulations, circuit diagram and code are shown below.

4 Bit modulo counter

[image]

Bit Slice

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
    --======================================================================
    entity counter_BitSlice is
      port (
        CLK    : in  std_logic;
        En     : in  std_logic;
        reset  : in  std_logic;

    OUTPUT   : out std_logic;
    AND_En  : out std_logic
    );
end counter_BitSlice;
--====================================================================
architecture struc of counter_BitSlice is
    signal XOr_En   : std_logic;
    signal En_In    : std_logic;
    signal Result   : std_logic;

begin

counter : process(CLK,XOr_En,reset,Result)
begin

If reset='1' then
XOr_En <='0';
OUTPUT <='0';
AND_En <='0';
Result <='0';
elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
    Result <= XOr_En;
end if;

XOr_En <= En_In XOR Result;
AND_En <= En_In AND Result;
OUTPUT <= Result;

En_In <= En;

end process counter;
end struc;
```

Structural VHDL

Here I was using a generate command for the slices but I hard coded it to eliminate errors

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
--======================================================================
entity counter is

  generic (
    BitLength : natural := 8
    );

  port (
    CLK : in std_logic;
    En_In   : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    OUTPUT : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    A_carry : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)

        );

end counter;
--======================================================================
architecture struc of counter is
  component counter_BitSlice
    port(
      CLK                 : in  std_logic;
      En                  : in  std_logic;
      reset               : in std_logic;
      AND_En              : out std_logic;
      OUTPUT              : out std_logic
      );
  end component;
--======================================================================
  signal AND_En_carry     : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUT_carry     : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
--======================================================================
  --CCHV_gen : for i in 1 to (BitLength) generate
  --begin

    CCHV_1 : counter_BitSlice
      port map(
        CLK    => CLK,
        reset  => reset,
        En   => En_In,
        AND_En => AND_En_carry(0),
        OUTPUT  => OUTPUT_carry(0)
        );
        CCHV_2 : counter_BitSlice
      port map(
        CLK    => CLK,
        reset  => reset,
        En   => AND_En_carry(0),
        AND_En => AND_En_carry(1),
        OUTPUT  => OUTPUT_carry(1)
        );
        CCHV_3 : counter_BitSlice
      port map(
        CLK    => CLK,
        reset  => reset,
        En   => AND_En_carry(1),
        AND_En => AND_En_carry(2),
        OUTPUT  => OUTPUT_carry(2)
        );
        CCHV_4 : counter_BitSlice
      port map(
        CLK    => CLK,
        reset  => reset,
        En   => AND_En_carry(2),
        AND_En => AND_En_carry(3),
        OUTPUT  => OUTPUT_carry(3)
        );
 -- end generate CCHV_gen;
    OUTPUT <= OUTPUT_carry;
    A_carry <= AND_En_carry;


  main : process(reset, CLK)
  begin
 if rising_edge(CLK) then 
  if reset ='1' then
  AND_En_carry <= (others=>'0');
  OUTPUT_carry <= (others =>'0');
  end if;
  end if;
  end process;
end architecture struc;
```

Test Bench for Bit Slice

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity tb_counter_BlitSlice is
end tb_counter_BlitSlice;

architecture tb_behav of tb_counter_BlitSlice is

  component counter_BlitSlice
    port(
      CLK                 : in  std_logic;
      En                 : in  std_logic;
      reset         : in std_logic;
      OUTPUT  : out std_logic;
      AND_En : out std_logic
      );
    end component;

  constant t_BitLength : natural :=8;
  signal t_En :std_logic := '0';
  signal t_CLK : std_logic :='0';
  signal t_reset : std_logic :='0';
  signal t_OUTPUT : std_logic :='0';
  signal t_AND_En  : std_logic :='0';

  begin

    U1: counter_BlitSlice
      port map ( 
        CLK => t_CLK,
        reset => t_reset,
        En => t_En,
        OUTPUT => t_OUTPUT,
        AND_En => t_AND_En
        );


    t_CLK <= not t_CLK after 20 ns;
    test : process
    begin
      t_En <= '0';
      t_reset <='0';
      wait for 20 ns;
      t_reset <='1';
      wait for 20 ns;
      t_reset <='0';
      wait for 20 ns;
      t_En <= '0';
      wait for 40 ns;
      t_En <= '1';
      wait for 20 ns;
      wait;
      end process test;
    end architecture tb_behav;
```

Test Bench for counter

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity tb_counter is
end tb_counter;

architecture tb_behav of tb_counter is

  component counter
  generic(
        BitLength : natural :=8
    );
    port(
      CLK                 : in  std_logic;
      En_In                 : in  std_logic;
      reset         : in std_logic;
      OUTPUT  : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      A_carry : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
      );
    end component;

  constant t_BitLength : natural :=8;
  signal t_En :std_logic := '0';
  signal t_CLK : std_logic :='0';
  signal t_reset : std_logic :='0';
  signal t_OUTPUT : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others =>'0');
  signal t_ANDcarry : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others =>'0');

  begin

    U1: counter
    generic map(
        BitLength => t_BitLength
    )
      port map ( 
        CLK => t_CLK,
        reset => t_reset,
        En_In => t_En,
        OUTPUT => t_OUTPUT,
        A_carry => t_ANDcarry
        );


    t_CLK <= not t_CLK after 20 ns;
    test : process
    begin
      t_En <= '0';
      t_reset <='0';
      wait for 20 ns;
      t_reset <='1';
      wait for 80 ns;
      t_reset <='0';
      wait for 60 ns;
      t_En <= '0';
      wait for 40 ns;
      t_En <= '1';
      wait for 20 ns;
      wait;
      end process test;
    end architecture tb_behav;
```

When I simulate the Bit Slice the output toggles correctly as seen below.

Bit Slice of Counter Simulation
[image]

And When I simulate the combined counter to get a four bit counter, it toggles between an unsigned value, as seen below. I don't understand what the issue is.

Counter Simulation
[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBjeg.png):

I took out the reset in the control.vhd and that got rid of the uknown signal, but its not counting correctly. as seem below.

[image: Counter Edit]

Comment: In the counter code, can you try removing this part:
  if reset ='1' then
  AND_En_carry <= (others=>'0');
  OUTPUT_carry <= (others =>'0');
  end if;
it looks like a multisource.

Comment: That got rid of the unknown number! However, it is not counting correctly. see image above. Thanks for the help

Comment: TL;DR. Multple assignment/driver error. Switch to `std_ulogic` types, so you can see where you make the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working after modifying the slice_counter code.

```
counter : process(CLK,reset)
begin

If reset='1' then
    OUTPUT <='0';
    Result <='0';
elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
    OUTPUT <= XOr_En;
   Result <= XOr_En;
end if;

end process counter;

XOr_En <= En XOR Result;
AND_En <= En AND Result;

end struc;
```

you should have put the AND and XOR gates outside the process. That was causing the error.

Comment: This answer would be improved substantially if it explained exactly what was wrong with the original code, and *why* the change suggested makes a difference.

Comment: You neglected removing unneeded registers not in the schematic both in counter_BitSlice (OUTPUT) and counter (remove process main, registers AND_En_carry and OUTPUT_carry) which gives you [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gejS4.png).